# Apparence of Vuetify3 components

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

In my Vue3/Vite/Vuetify3 app, the appearance of some components (button, text field, ...) is not identical to the Vuetify standard. For example the button does not have the default elevation and the text font is thin.Text fields have a yellow background instead of the standard gray.

My main.ts file :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

// Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi
    }
  },
})

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(vuetify)
app.mount('#app')
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Try inspecting the DOM and seeing what other styles are being applied and from where.  You should also be able to see if styles from Vuetify stylesheets exist and if they're being overridden.